# Removed groups in subsite sharepoint2013?

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups, auditing

Some one removed the groups in a subsite, again i added the groups, is it possible t know who removed the groups  in sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure auditing for this. If you have already configured the auditing u=you can check in your audit logs . Otherwise you can configure it as follow:

https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

so that you can audit next time.